# Change great-grandparent directory name while preserving project integrity (IntelliJ / Python)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, intellij-idea, directory

I'm looking for a way to change the name of the great-grandparent directory in the filepath to my project while still maintaining the integrity/structure of my IntelliJ projects.

The reason I am doing this:

I am creating virtual environments for my projects now which works well, however, when I try to pip3 install a package I get an error because there is a SPACE in my great-grandparent directory name.  PIP cannot handle having a space in the directory name and, although I've attempted to escape it with a backslash, it still will not work (the path still tries to stop at the space after the backslash and treat everything else as arguments).  In addition, I've found in my reading that pip can have a hard time with very long path names as well which I have experienced when the path becomes suitably long (I haven't counted, but probably about 80 characters).

I'd like to change something like this:

/Users/myname/Python Projects/grandparent_directory/parent_directory/directory/file

to this:

/Users/myname/Python_Projects/grandparent_directory/parent_directory/directory/file

(Note that in the second path I've replaced the space in 'Python Projects' with an underscore).

Doing so with a parent directory would be trivial because I could easily rebuild my IntelliJ project by just adding the files back in manually.  The problem is that the offending directory holds ALL of my python projects in sub-directories.  Trying this initially caused IntelliJ to be unable to find the appropriate files for each project and will require me to manually reconstruct the structure of every python project I have.

When I created this directory I became concerned early on about the space in the directory name but didn't address it at the time.  Now my number of projects has grown quite large and I'm hoping to address it before the problem becomes worse.

Comment: FWIW, it seems the space issue is fixed in pip 10: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/923

Comment: @Ssswift thank you, I wasn't aware. I'm actually not sure which pip I'm using but I'll make sure to go to pip 10 and try.

Comment: @Ssswift is there a release date set for pip 10?  When I looked it still seemed 9.0.1 was the most recent version.  When I ran 'pip install pip -U' I get the message back 'Requirement already satisfied'.

Comment: Hanzy: Not according to https://github.com/pypa/pip/milestone/23